# GWT RPC only handle results from the last call(back)

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc

I'm wondering if there is a cleaner and more re-usable way to implement the following use case:

I have a search form that sends a RPC to the server with the user entered values. The callback returns the items that match the search criteria. A search can take several seconds and we want the user to be able to alter his search criteria even if the previous search hasn't completed yet. If he does this, all previous search results should be ignored and the last result should be presented. If we don't take this in account, sometimes the newest call will return before the older ones resulting in the newest results getting overridden, which means the presented results won't match the currently entered criteria.

We currently solve this by assigning the callback to a "lastCallback" field. Each callback instance can access this field and checks whether the field is equal to itself. If not, a newer search request has been sent in the meantime and thus the results of this old call are ignored.

Does GWT provide a built-in way to handle this use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cancel the previous calls. Have your async methods return `com.google.gwt.http.client.Request` instead of `void`, so you can call `cancel()` on it. This would make sure your *previous callback* will never be called and you only ever have one ongoing request (from the client's point of view at least; you'll have several being processed on the server because cancelling a request is a client and network thing, and isn't exposed to the servlet server-side)

Comment: Thanks! This was the built-in feature I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is correct.

This is not a GWT issue - once a browser makes a call to the server, the server is going to respond - whether you need this response or not. So you have to have a flag someone to decide which response is unwanted.

Answer (score -1):

One optimization could be to just return null or a specific exception from the server for the first request, when a second request arrives during a search progress.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this optimization would force me to check which clients the requests belong to and keep state server side to determine whether it is indeed a new request. I think this workaround would be a bit too intrusive.

Comment: Right, but since you would only have to put and check some flags in the user's session, it should not be such a great deal. Depending on your requirements the optimization could be quite useful because maybe you could abort an ongoing, unnecessary search.